# Какие команды можно передавать в system(" ")

Tags: c++

Мне известно пару команд: `system("cls")`, `system("pause")`, например.
Напишите, пожалуйста, какие еще команды можно использовать в system(" ") и что они выполняют.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если под Windows, тогда вот

1. ASSOC    Вывод либо изменение сопоставлений по расширениям имен файлов.
2. AT       Выполнение команд и запуск программ по расписанию.
3. ATTRIB   Отображение и изменение атрибутов файлов.
4. BREAK    Включение/выключение режима обработки комбинации клавиш CTRL+C
5. CACLS    Отображение/редактирование списков управления доступом (ACL) к файлам.
6. CALL     Вызов одного пакетного файла из другого.
7. CD       Вывод имени либо смена текущей папки.
8. CHCP     Вывод либо установка активной кодовой страницы.
9. CHDIR    Вывод имени либо смена текущей папки.
10. CHKDSK   Проверка диска и вывод статистики.
11. CHKNTFS  Отображение или изменение выполнения проверки диска во время загрузки.
12. CLS      Очистка экрана.
13. CMD      Запуск еще одного интерпретатора командных строк Windows.
14. COLOR    Установка цвета текста и фона, используемых по умолчанию.
15. COMP     Сравнение содержимого двух файлов или двух наборов файлов.
16. COMPACT  Отображение/изменение сжатия файлов в разделах NTFS.
17. CONVERT  Преобразование дисковых томов FAT в NTFS. Нельзя выполнить
    преобразование текущего активного диска.
18. COPY     Копирование одного или нескольких файлов в другое место.
19. DATE     Вывод либо установка текущей даты.
20. DEL      Удаление одного или нескольких файлов.
21. DIR      Вывод списка файлов и подпапок из указанной папки.
22. DISKCOMP Сравнение содержимого двух гибких дисков.
23. DISKCOPY Копирование содержимого одного гибкого диска на другой.
24. DOSKEY   Редактирование и повторный вызов командных строк; создание макросов.
25. ECHO     Вывод сообщений и переключение режима отображения команд на экране.
26. ENDLOCAL Конец локальных изменений среды для пакетного файла.
27. ERASE    Удаление одного или нескольких файлов.
28. EXIT     Завершение работы программы CMD.EXE (интерпретатора командных строк).
29. FC       Сравнение двух файлов или двух наборов файлов и вывод различий между
    ними.
30. FIND     Поиск текстовой строки в одном или нескольких файлах.
31. FINDSTR  Поиск строк в файлах.
32. FOR      Запуск указанной команды для каждого из файлов в наборе.
33. FORMAT   Форматирование диска для работы с Windows.
34. FTYPE    Вывод либо изменение типов файлов, используемых при сопоставлении по
    расширениям имен файлов.
35. GOTO     Передача управления в отмеченную строку пакетного файла.
36. GRAFTABL Позволяет Windows отображать расширенный набор символов в графическом
    режиме.
37. HELP     Выводит справочную информацию о командах Windows.
38. IF       Оператор условного выполнения команд в пакетном файле.
39. LABEL    Создание, изменение и удаление меток тома для дисков.
40. MD       Создание папки.
41. MKDIR    Создание папки
42. MODE     Конфигурирование системных устройств.
43. MORE     Последовательный вывод данных по частям размером в один экран.
44. MOVE     Перемещение одного или нескольких файлов из одной папки в другую.
45. PATH     Вывод либо установка пути поиска исполняемых файлов.
46. PAUSE    Приостановка выполнения пакетного файла и вывод сообщения.
47. POPD     Восстановление предыдущего значения текущей активной папки,
    сохраненного с помощью команды PUSHD.
48. PRINT    Вывод на печать содержимого текстовых файлов.
49. PROMPT   Изменение приглашения в командной строке Windows.
50. PUSHD    Сохранение значения текущей активной папки и переход к другой папке.
51. RD       Удаление папки.
52. RECOVER  Восстановление читаемой информации с плохого или поврежденного диска.
53. REM      Помещение комментариев в пакетные файлы и файл CONFIG.SYS.
54. REN      Переименование файлов и папок.
55. RENAME   Переименование файлов и папок.
56. REPLACE  Замещение файлов.
57. RMDIR    Удаление папки.
58. SET      Вывод, установка и удаление переменных среды Windows.
59. SETLOCAL Начало локальных изменений среды для пакетного файла.
60. SHIFT    Изменение содержимого (сдвиг) подставляемых параметров для пакетного
    файла.
61. SORT     Сортировка ввода.
62. START    Запуск программы или команды в отдельном окне.
63. SUBST    Сопоставляет заданному пути имя диска.
64. TIME     Вывод и установка системного времени.
65. TITLE    Назначение заголовка окна для текущего сеанса интерпретатора
    командных строк CMD.EXE.
66. TREE     Графическое отображение структуры папок заданного диска или заданной
    папки.
67. TYPE     Вывод на экран содержимого текстовых файлов.
68. VER      Вывод сведений о версии Windows.
69. VERIFY   Установка режима проверки правильности записи файлов на диск.
70. VOL      Вывод метки и серийного номера тома для диска.
71. XCOPY    Копирование файлов и дерева папок.

[список команд](http://covorp.com/useful/spisok-komand-dlya-paketnogo-bat-cmd-faila)

Comment: Приведите основную информацию в самом ответе, а не по ссылке

Comment: свежайший материал однако

Comment: Вообще, бесконечно, потому что можно положить `exe` в файл, добавить путь в `PATH` и запустить также.

Comment: @Egorithm, ну бесконечно я бы не выдержал переписывать, это в разы больше чем 71)

Answer (score 8):

в функцию `system` можно передавать любые команды, которые могут быть выполнены в командном процессоре или терминале операционной системы

---

следует знать, что вызов этой функции ресурсоемок, а также использование этой функции делает программы не переносимой между различными системами, так как различные ОС имеют разные команды

---

для просмотра самых популярных команд windows можно ввести команду `help` в терминале, или вызвать функцию `system` с командой `help` в с++ программе на windows, все команды можно просмотреть в онлайн документации