# Как убрать из консоли текст который ты написал через "cin"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string str;
string word;
string login = str;
string password = word;
int main(int, char**)
{
    cin >> str;
    cin >> word;
    cout << "You are loggined in!" << endl;
    cin >> login;
    cin >> password;
    if (str + word == login + password)
    {
        cout << "Hi, Welcome back!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (str + word != login + password)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect login or password!";
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

помогите пожалуйста, решил начать изучать c++ и пытался сделать систему регистрации (знаю, глупо) и во время того как я ввожу текст в консоль этот текст остаётся, а мне надо чтобы он убрался.
Например:
ты вводишь:

```
"Dan" и он исчезает
"777" и он исчезает
```

Answer (score -1):

`system("cls");` - очистка консоли

можно к примеру после авторизации полностью очищать консоль

Answer (score -2):

```
system("cls");
```

Очистка консоли.

В функцию system можно передавать любые команды, которые могут быть выполнены в командном процессоре или терминале операционной системы.
[Команды под Windows можно здесь подсмотреть.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165677/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-system)